# What is this category of paradox called

Tags: paradox

In March 2020 the manager of the group scheduled a daily 15 minute meeting that was supposed to repeat until "things are back to normal."

By October 2022, the new state of things is normal, including having this meeting, which should thus end. But it can't end because without the meeting things are deviating from what is normal.

Comment: It is a variant of [Berry paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_paradox), "the smallest positive integer not definable in under sixty letters". One never reaches such an integer because if it were to be reached the phrase's meaning would shift, making it definable. "The time when things are back to normal" is viciously ambiguous in the same way.

Comment: Life never gets back to normal.

Comment: This sounds like the usual category of semantic indeterminacy of common natural language words which could become very vague and plastic such as your "things" and "normal", especially after a long period of time as social background evolves continuously...